TikTok API: Search ID is invalid or expired
I am trying to fetch Videos from TikTok. However, Always after some pages the search ID expires. I did not yet find a way to handle that because since there is this error, I am only scraping part of the videos I want to scrape.
Scraping videos from 20230601 to 20230630
Error: {"error":{"code":"invalid_params","message":"Search Id 7395182553051026478 is invalid or expired","log_id":"20240724132313EB6CA0C6D69DB0024E1A"}}

Have you figured this out? I'm running into the same issue with the query videos research API and so I'm unable to loop my API calls to get the full results list.
